# Setting the background color of a table cell in Word [docx] [Python 3.8.2]

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I'm having problems understanding how to set the background color of a table cell.

I tried many combinations, but the only thing I managed to do was the to set the paragraph style.

```
import docx    

doc = docx.Document()

records = (
    (3, '101', 'Spam'),
    (7, '422', 'Eggs'),
    (4, '631', 'Spam, spam, eggs, and spam')
    )

table = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)

hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Qty'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'Id'
hdr_cells[2].text = 'Desc'
for qty, id, desc in records:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].add_paragraph(str(qty), "Title 1")
    row_cells[0].text_frame.paragraph[0].font.size = Pt(12)
    row_cells[1].text = id
    row_cells[2].text = desc

doc.save("Testing.docx")
```

I would like to set row_cells[0] to have a red background, but I'm unable to do it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That option is still not supported by the official python-docx library.
However, you can try implementing it yourself. The property you're looking for is called [cell shading](http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableCellProperties-Shading.php) located under [cell properties](http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableCellProperties.php).

Solution:
Add the shading element(`w:shd`) to the cell properties(`w:tcPr`).

Wrote the simple function that does exactly that:

```
def _set_cell_background(cell, fill, color=None, val=None):
    """
    @fill: Specifies the color to be used for the background
    @color: Specifies the color to be used for any foreground
    pattern specified with the val attribute
    @val: Specifies the pattern to be used to lay the pattern
    color over the background color.
    """
    from docx.oxml.shared import qn  # feel free to move these out
    from docx.oxml.xmlchemy import OxmlElement

    cell_properties = cell._element.tcPr
    try:
        cell_shading = cell_properties.xpath('w:shd')[0]  # in case there's already shading
    except IndexError:
        cell_shading = OxmlElement('w:shd') # add new w:shd element to it
    if fill:
        cell_shading.set(qn('w:fill'), fill)  # set fill property, respecting namespace
    if color:
        pass # TODO
    if val:
        pass # TODO
    cell_properties.append(cell_shading)  # finally extend cell props with shading element
```

Feel free to extend other properties if you need em.

So based on your example, once you have your table, before saving the doc, add this line:

```
.
.
_set_cell_background(table.rows[0].cells[0], 'FF0000')
doc.save("Testing.docx")
```

Also, feel free to contribute to the official library by registering this new element here: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/table.py#L753. :)

Hope this helps,